# Remove adverts from browser when running servlet

Tags: servlets

I have a servlet running from Eclipse IDE on Tomcat 7. In the code I have no adverts whatsoever, however when I load the page on my browser adverts keep showing up at the bottom of the page. I clicked on inspect element and there were 2  elements which does not exist in my code. I tried to click on delete node and the adverts were removed.. but whenever I reload the page they keep showing up again.

Any ideas on how I can remove them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If they're not in your code, then they exist somewhere between the response and the client.

As an example, some service providers insert ads into responses.

Obviously you cannot remove ads using server side code if they're not inserted by your server.

You need to find out where in the request/response process the ads are inserted. Put a filter around your requests to examine the response and ensure they're not being inserted by your server.

If they're not, they're from somewhere in the middle, but without further information, it will be difficult to assist much further.